# Qt C++ How to connect a class's instance from other class

Tags: c++, qt

I have three C++ classes: `DB`, `MainWindow` and `Login`. The instance of `DB` resides as `database` in `MainWindow`, and a button calls the instance of `Login` called `loginDialog`. Now I want to connect `loginDialog`'s `accept()` with `database`'s (`DB`'s) slot, but since the instance `database` resides in `MainWindow`, I'm confused as to how to access it.

*DB.h*

```cpp
public:
    void login(QString name,QString id,QString pass);
```

*DB.cpp*

```cpp
void DB::login(QString name, QString id,QString pass){
    qInfo()<<"Login approved";    //placeholder
}
```

*MainWindow.h*

```cpp
private:
    DB database;
public slots:
    void dblogin(QString name,QString id,QString pass);
private slots:
    void showLoginPage();
```

*MainWindow.cpp*

```cpp
#include "Login.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):QDialog(parent),ui(new Ui::MainWindow){
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&MainWindow::showLoginPage);
}
void MainWindow::dblogin(QString name, QString id, QString pass){
    database.login(name,id,pass);
}
void MainWindow::showLoginPage(){
    Login loginDialog;
    loginDialog.exec();
}
```

*Login.h*

```cpp
signals:
    void makeLogin(QString name,QString id,QString pass);
private slots:
    void startLogin();
```

*Login.cpp*

```cpp
Login::Login(QWidget *parent):QDialog(parent),ui(new Ui::Login){
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(this,&QDialog::accept,this,&Login::startLogin);
    connect(this,&Login::makeLogin,&MainWindow,&MainWindow::dblogin);    //Error
}
void Login::startLogin(){
    emit makeLogin(ui->f1->text(),ui->f2->text(),ui->f3->text());
}
```

Comment: You could make MainWindow the parent `Login loginDialog(this);` and use `connect(this,&Login::makeLogin,parent,&MainWindow::dblogin);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @drescherjm. How many parent instances can I access using this if (suppose) `MainWindow` itself is a child of another base class called `IOController`?

Comment: There is no limit to this. It's essentially a linked list.

Comment: So if I use `parent()->parent()`, will I be able to access the `IOController`'s slots?

Comment: You should be able to do that if `MainWindow` is a parent of  `IOController`.  Normally the MainWIndow is created in `int main()` and not a child of some other QObject.

Comment: @drescherjm unfortunately, using `parent` in `connect` does not work. MainWindow is being parsed as `QWidget*&`

Comment: Are you getting a compiler error because QWidget* should be fine since MainWindow derives from QWidget?

Comment: It's a compile error

Comment: You probably have to show the exact text of the error message.

Comment: login.cpp:10: error: no matching function for call to `Login::connect(Login*, void (Login::*)(QString, QString, QString), QWidget*&, void (MainWindow::*)(QString, QString, QString))`

login.cpp: In constructor `Login::Login(QWidget*)`:

login.cpp:10:16: error: no matching function for call to `Login::connect(Login*, void (Login::*)(QString, QString, QString), QWidget*&, void (MainWindow::*)(QString, QString, QString))`

   10 |         `connect(this,&Login::makeLogin,parent,&MainWindow::dblogin);`

Comment: login.cpp:10: error: invalid conversion from ‘QWidget*’ to ‘const Object*’ {aka ‘const MainWindow*’} [-fpermissive]

/QTCreator/6.4.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:201:43: note:   conversion of argument 3 would be ill-formed:
/login.cpp:10:40: error: invalid conversion from ‘QWidget*’ to ‘const Object*’ {aka ‘const MainWindow*’} [-fpermissive]
   10 |         connect(this,&Login::makeLogin,parent,&MainWindow::dblogin);
      |                                        ^~~~~~
      |                                        |
      |                                        QWidget*

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, make `MainWindow` the parent of `Login` and make the connection.
I suggest also that your `IOController` should be a member of `MainWindow` so that everything would be centered.

If things get complicated with connections, you can access to public members of MainWindow like that :

```
    auto theParent = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(this->parent());
    if(theParent)
    {
        // access to any member of MainWindow
    }
```